# Change table owner for newly created tables under a given schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I execute `select Name, user_name(schema_id) as TableOwner, user_name(principal_id) as SchemaOwner from sys.schemas` query on SQL, then it will provide me a list of all the schemas in my database along with the owner under which new tables will be created using the respective schema and owner of the schema. E.g. schema: xyz, TableOwner:Matt , SchemaOwner:dbo. This TableOwner would be same for all the tables created using 'xyz' schema.

How can i change this TableOwner value?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? (If yes, add <sql-server> tag to the question.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You use [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql)

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::SchemaName TO CustomUser
```